# Creating webservice in Yii issue:

Tags: php, web-services, yii

This is my code Yii framework:

```
 class ServiceController extends Controller {

            public function actions() {
                return array(
                    'wsdl' => array(
                        'class' => 'CWebServiceAction',
                        'serviceOptions'=>array('soapVersion'=>'1.2'),
                        'classMap'=>array(
                            'Customers',
                        ),
                    ),
                );
            }
/**
         * @param string
         * @return string
         * @soap
         */
             public function sayHello($test){
                return $test;
             }
    }
```

This class generate me this type of xml:

```
<definitions name="ServiceController" targetNamespace="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl">
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="test" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="sayHelloResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="return" type="xsd:struct"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ServiceControllerPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
                <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHelloRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServiceControllerBinding" type="tns:ServiceControllerPortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl#sayHello" style="rpc"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:ServiceControllerwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ServiceControllerService">
        <wsdl:port name="ServiceControllerPort" binding="tns:ServiceControllerBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://webs.softvision.ro/api/service/wsdl/ws/1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</definitions>
```

**I have to create my xml to look like this example:**

```
<WL5G3N0:definitions targetNamespace="http://helloworld.webservice.moodykettle.com">
    <WL5G3N0:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://helloworld.webservice.moodykettle.com">
        <xsd:element name="sayHello">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="sayHelloResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="sayHelloReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="visitTimestampReq">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="reqMsg" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="visitTimestampResp">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="respMsg" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    </WL5G3N0:types>
    <WL5G3N0:message name="sayHelloResponse">
        <WL5G3N0:part element="WL5G3N1:sayHelloResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </WL5G3N0:message>
    <WL5G3N0:message name="sayHelloRequest">
        <WL5G3N0:part element="WL5G3N1:sayHello" name="parameters"/>
    </WL5G3N0:message>
    <WL5G3N0:message name="visitTimestampReq">
        <WL5G3N0:part element="WL5G3N1:visitTimestampReq" name="parameters"/>
    </WL5G3N0:message>
    <WL5G3N0:message name="visitTimestampResp">
        <WL5G3N0:part element="WL5G3N1:visitTimestampResp" name="parameters"/>
    </WL5G3N0:message>
    <WL5G3N0:portType name="HelloWorld">
            <WL5G3N0:operation name="sayHello">
                <WL5G3N0:input message="WL5G3N1:sayHelloRequest" name="sayHelloRequest"/>
                    <WL5G3N0:output message="WL5G3N1:sayHelloResponse" name="sayHelloResponse"/>
                </WL5G3N0:operation>
            <WL5G3N0:operation name="visitTimestampDetails">
                <WL5G3N0:input message="WL5G3N1:visitTimestampReq"/>
                <WL5G3N0:output message="WL5G3N1:visitTimestampResp"/>
            </WL5G3N0:operation>
    </WL5G3N0:portType>
    <WL5G3N0:binding name="HelloWorldSoapBinding" type="WL5G3N1:HelloWorld">
    <WL5G3N2:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <WL5G3N0:operation name="sayHello">
        <WL5G3N2:operation/>
            <WL5G3N0:input name="sayHelloRequest">
                <WL5G3N2:body use="literal"/>
            </WL5G3N0:input>
            <WL5G3N0:output name="sayHelloResponse">
                <WL5G3N2:body use="literal"/>
            </WL5G3N0:output>
        </WL5G3N0:operation>
        <WL5G3N0:operation name="visitTimestampDetails">
            <WL5G3N2:operation/>
            <WL5G3N0:input name="visitTimestampReq">
                <WL5G3N2:body/>
            </WL5G3N0:input>
            <WL5G3N0:output name="visitTimestampResp">
                <WL5G3N2:body/>
            </WL5G3N0:output>
        </WL5G3N0:operation>
    </WL5G3N0:binding>
    <WL5G3N0:service name="HelloWorldSoapBindingQSService">
        <WL5G3N0:documentation>
            Service 2
        </WL5G3N0:documentation>
        <WL5G3N0:port binding="WL5G3N1:HelloWorldSoapBinding" name="HelloWorldSoapBindingQSPort">
            <WL5G3N2:address location="http://unitxxxx/SayHello/HelloWorldImplPipe-proxy"/>
        </WL5G3N0:port>
    </WL5G3N0:service>
</WL5G3N0:definitions>
```

I don't understand how should I create this type of xml ? I am a newbie to this! Any idea how I make my webservice to return this XML ?

Comment: anyone, any idea ? :)